# is it possible to use CTE expression in teradata TPT script?

Tags: teradata, common-table-expression

I have a complex teradata query that runs in a TPT script using Export operator ans selectStmt attribute.
When I refactored the query using CTE I get

```
: TPT10508: RDBMS error 3706: Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the word 'with\
TMP_ABO'.
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to use CTE in this case.

Comment: The FastExport protocol / EXPORT operator does not support CTE. It does support derived table syntax in the FROM clause. Or if the data volume is not large, consider the SQL_SELECTOR operator which does support CTE.

Comment: Thx. I have a complex query with millions of lines. So the best choice is the fastExport. right ?

Comment: Yes - if the query returns millions of rows, you probably want to use Export operator (FastExport protocol). So either create a view with the CTE and reference that view in the SelectStmt, or change the syntax to use e.g. `SELECT ... FROM (subquery) Q1` instead of `WITH Q1 AS (subquery) SELECT ... FROM Q1`